# Linux uses 6.6Gi RAM for nothing

Tags: debian, memory, out-of-memory

I'm trying to figure out why my Linux machine is so slow and I found this:

```
$ free --human
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,3Gi       6,6Gi       168Mi       1,0Gi       1,8Gi       746Mi
Swap:          9,3Gi       2,7Gi       6,6Gi
```

When I run `top -n1 -b -o+RES | head -n20` I can't see any process that uses so much memory. Even the cache is not filled this much.

```
top - 07:37:45 up 23 min,  2 users,  load average: 1,31, 1,41, 1,04
Tasks: 272 total,   1 running, 271 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8,7 us, 13,0 sy,  0,0 ni, 78,3 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st 
MiB Mem :   7457,6 total,    150,1 free,   5718,4 used,   2481,4 buff/cache     
MiB Swap:   9536,0 total,   9524,2 free,     11,8 used.   1739,2 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   5038 isumis    20   0 2122864   1,3g  23568 S   0,0  17,8   0:42.42 rust-an+
   3675 isumis    20   0   11,5g 401788 167268 S   0,0   5,3   4:52.22 firefox+
   3883 isumis    20   0   38,7g 327144  78416 S   0,0   4,3   1:32.40 WebExte+
   2712 isumis    20   0 3909688 275568 112448 S   0,0   3,6   0:46.07 plasmas+
   7724 isumis    20   0 2718576 240288  79788 S   0,0   3,1   1:39.39 Isolate+
   8244 isumis    20   0 2654028 214240  95748 S   0,0   2,8   0:16.32 Isolate+
   7926 isumis    20   0 1123,1g 211408 119956 S   0,0   2,8   0:04.49 1passwo+
   8283 isumis    20   0 2621440 183860 101344 S   0,0   2,4   0:16.16 Isolate+
   8142 isumis    20   0 2595336 176064  96568 S   5,6   2,3   0:13.75 Isolate+
   1179 root      20   0 1691464 171008  25304 S   0,0   2,2   0:19.97 dockerd
   7992 isumis    20   0   32,3g 160576  41824 S   0,0   2,1   0:01.14 1passwo+
   4908 isumis    20   0 1130,9g 156720  58864 S   0,0   2,1   0:11.68 code
   4808 isumis    20   0 1122,0g 144336  53780 S   0,0   1,9   0:05.30 code
```

Even after closing VS Code (rust analyzer) there is still 3GB in use.

Is there something I can do to figure out the problem?

I'm using Debian 12 on a Lenovo T470p.

Comment: something must be using that memory, clearly we can't find it

Comment: `top` sorts by cpu use by default when you first open it. Press “Shift” M to sort by memory use

Comment: `top -n1 -b -o+RES | head -n20` should give you a handle on processes with a large resident set size (i.e. processes using the most memory). You could also try `%MEM` instead of `RES`.

Comment: It's not a problem

Comment: It's not a problem  The memory is used as cache, and will be released at need.

Comment: @waltinator I'm seeing only 1.8Gi being used as cache

Comment: I don't see any Linux process here in your `top` output. So, your title is wrong in 2 ways. (1) Linux uses and (2) for nothing. Unfortunately, we cannot see the full commands, but you seem to run some processes, I guess inside your `docker` containers that consume the memory.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: @symcbean I don't quite think so. There's 1.8GB used as cache but the OP couldn't identify the remaining 4.8GB. My answer helps identify that but as such I don't think it's directly a linuxatmyram issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RES column in your output from `top` shows the amount of physical memory used by each process. (The memory used by a process that is RESident in physical memory. This is distinct from VIRTual memory allocated by each process.) Just in the subset shown there is 4GB used.

There is 1.8GB used as cache. This can be discarded *automatically* by the system as soon as there is a real need for physical memory (contrary to some posters elsewhere you do not need to drop these caches manually). That brings the total used to 5.8GB.

You provide information about 13 processes of 272. I would say it's quite possible that there are enough processes unlisted to consume the remaining 0.8GB that you mention in the question title.